# Python regex for this string

Tags: python, regex

What would be the python regex for the following string?

```
"111(A5)A05209(May)2005"
```

I want to get the values:

```
   111
   A5
   A05209
   May
   2005
```

Thanks!

Comment: You know... you should post your attempt as well. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: One possible (and trivial) regex for that string would be `111\(A5\)A05209\(May\)2005`. I think what you're looking for is more likely a way to split the string on a set of delimiters (i.e. `re.split()`)...

Answer (score 5):

Simply use [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split). Probably the most intuitive method.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[\(\)]', "111(A5)A05209(May)2005")
['111', 'A5', 'A05209', 'May', '2005']
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest

```
s = " 111(A5)A05209(May)2005"
s.replace('(', ' ').replace(')', ' ')
values = s.split()
>> ['111', 'A5', 'A05209', 'May', '2005']
```

The regexp way would be

```
import re
s = re.findall(r'\w+', s)
>> ['111', 'A5', 'A05209', 'May', '2005']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` and `str.join`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "111(A5)A05209(May)2005"
>>> print "\n".join(re.findall(r'\w+',strs))
111
A5
A05209
May
2005
```

or `re.sub`:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'[\W]+','\n',strs)
111
A5
A05209
May
2005
```

Another alternative is `str.translate`:

```
>>> from string import punctuation, whitespace, maketrans
>>> intab = punctuation + whitespace
>>> outtab = "\n"*len(intab)
>>> print strs.translate(trantab)
111
A5
A05209
May
2005
```

In terms of performance `str.translate` is far better than `regex`:

```
>>> strs = "111(A5)A05209(May)2005"*1000
>>> %timeit "\n".join(re.findall(r'\w+',strs))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.19 ms per loop
>>> %timeit re.sub(r'[\W]+','\n',strs)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.43 ms per loop
>>> %timeit strs.translate(trantab)
10000 loops, best of 3: 93.9 us per loop
```

Comment: Dammit! You thwart me again! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> str = '111(A5)A05209(May)2005'
>>> print str.replace('(','\n').replace(')','\n')
111
A5
A05209
May
2005
```